# Update widget from other widget if they are in 2 different dart file

Tags: dart, flutter

Creating a sample calculator app in flutter. But no idea how to communicate each widgets, which are different dart files.

- Main.dart  ---------- ( starting point of the application)
- CalculatorFrame.dart  --------- ( importing numberboards , entry textbox and 
   forms calculator view)
- NumberButton.dart -------- ( represent the button widget)
- NumberBoards.dart  ---------- ( import numberbutton and creates the buttons ( 0-9) portion of the calculator)
- EntryTextbox.dart  ----------- ( represent the textbox entry for button pressed action and calculated values)

I have a difficulty to implement the interaction with these widgets. On button pressed, need to update the EntryTextbox widget. How can it be done if the widgets are in different dart files.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

- 1.) You need to make your CalculatorFrame a `Stateful` widget.
- 2.) You need to create a state for your `EntryTextbox` widget like a `userInput` state to track what the current user input was.
- 3.) You need to create a method to update the state by using the `setState` method that is built in when using the `Stateful` widget.
- 4.) You need to pass that method to the `NumberBoards` then create a constructor to receive that method then pass the method to the `NumberButton` widget.

Comment: You can use the [BLOC pattern](https://medium.com/flutterpub/architecting-your-flutter-project-bd04e144a8f1) or use the [flutter_redux](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_redux) or [scoped model](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scoped_model) for state management. But i usually prefer redux because it is more easy to implement in even small projects or large projects.

Answer (score 3):

To change the state of `EntryTextbox` widget when a button was pressed, declare a containing widget (I suppose it's `CalculatorFrame`) as `StatefullWidget` with `String` or whatever field, which you will initialize `EntryTextbox` from. Implement a function that changes that field when a button is pressed, and pass it as a constructor parameter to a `NumberButton` widget.
Here is a schematic example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CalculatorFrame extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CalculatorFrameState createState() => _CalculatorFrameState();
}

class _CalculatorFrameState extends State<CalculatorFrame> {
  String _text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ...( // container widget of your choice
    EntryTextbox(text: _text),
    NumberButton(text: '0', onPressed: _onPressed,),
    ...,
    NumberButton(text: '9', onPressed: _onPressed,),
  );

  void _onPressed(String buttonText) =>
      setState(() => _text += buttonText);
}

class EntryTextbox extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const EntryTextbox({Key key, this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ...(text: text); // text entry widget of your choice
}

class NumberButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Function(String) onPressed;

  const NumberButton({Key key, this.onPressed, this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ...Button( // button widget of your choice
    child: Text(text),
    onPressed: () => onPressed(text),
  );
}
```

Since in your example `NumberButton` widgets sit inside `NumberBoards` widget, it's `NumberBoards` responsibility to accept `onPressed` as a constructor parameter and pass it to each `NumberButton` constructor.
In my example, `onPressed` accepts `String` parameter - text of the button which was pressed. You might decide to pass `int` or perhaps a more complex data class.

This non-architectural approach works fine for tiny apps and samples. However, I'd rather recommend using BLoC or ScopedModel for your task. [Simple app state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) section of the official documentation might be helpful.